# YouTube Videos in Full Screen Stuttering, Jittering and 'Lagging' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, video, amd-graphics, youtube

When I run a full screen video on Ubuntu 20.04 on Firefox, or Chromium, the video jitters and skips frames in full screen mode. Videos look absolutely fine in standard mode.

My GPU is the AMD Radeon RX 550 on a HP Z600 workstation with 32gb RAM and x2 Xeons making a total of 12 cores.

I have already tried a few solutions, including some drivers, but mainly turning off hardware acceleration. When I ran Windows 10 on the machine, I never had any similar issues, which makes me think it's a driver issue.

[See a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41T6Y.jpg)

Edit: I should also mention that games like Minecraft run smoothly and well, which I'd assume is more demanding than streaming 1080p video.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I'm also having this same issue. My computer has a ryzen 1800x with 16Gb of DDR4 ram and 1070 GPU.

Video playback is smooth in standard or theatrical mode but as soon as I make it full screen it will skip a lot of frames.

EDIT- Just updated GPU drivers and now it's running smoothly even in full screen. I was previously using generic drivers.

Comment: Yeah, I think my issue was drivers. I've now switched to POP_OS! which is known for being good with drivers and I've not had an issue since.

Answer (score -1):

Because this is also a swap.

Try running the `free -s1` command in the terminal when this happens.

Try disabling the swap flag in your browser settings.